# NPE when getArguments() from a class that extends fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

In the below code, I am trying to pass values from `mainactivity` whose layout has `<fragment>` tab to another class that extends `fragment` using `setArgument()` and `getArgument()`. When run the App. logcate throws `NPE`. what I am missing in the code?

MainActivity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Fragment mSelectedFragment = null;

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn00:    
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        String clicks = Integer.toString(i);
        mBundle.putString("btn1_clicks", clicks);
        mSelectedFragment = new Fragment00();
        mSelectedFragment.setArguments(mBundle);

        if (mSelectedFragment != null) {
            FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment00ID, mSelectedFragment).commit();
        }
        i ++;
        break;
    }
```

Class_extends_fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment00, null);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mTv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment00Tv00);
    /*line 32->*/String str = getArguments().getString("btn1_clicks").toString();
    mTv.setText("the Button was clicked "+str+ " time(s)");
    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityCreated(): "+getArguments().getString("btn1_clicks").toString());
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-27 13:36:14.380: E/AndroidRuntime(11609): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 
start activity    
ComponentInfo{com.example.fragments01/com.example.fragments01.MainActivity}:  
java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 13:36:14.380: E/AndroidRuntime(11609):    at  
com.example.fragments01.Fragment00.onActivityCreated(Fragment00.java:32)
05-27 13:36:14.380: E/AndroidRuntime(11609):    at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1860)
```

Comment: What is the line (Fragment00.java:32)?

Comment: @algui91 Fragment00 is the name of the class that extends fragment

Comment: No, I want the line on what the exception occurs, the logcat says is line 32 of your Fragment00.java file. And also in `i ++` you have an space, it should be `i++`

Comment: Do you override `onCreateView()` in your `Fragment00`? If you don't, `getView` will return `null`.

Comment: @algui91 please the updated code with indication where line 32 is

Comment: @curtisLoew please the updated code. yes it is overriden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I think is that you are retrieving `getArguments()` on `onActivityCreated` and there  you didn't create the bundle yet (You are creating it in the `onClick`). You should either check if `getArguments()` returns null or create your bundle out of the `onClick`.

Former version would be:

```
if (getArguments() != null){
    String str = getArguments().getString("btn1_clicks").toString();
}
```

Comment: but i am calling `getargument` inside `onActivityCreated()`, where should i call it from? and what could cause the bundle not to be created?

Comment: Until you don't click at least once the fragment, the bundle is not being created, and `onActivityCreated` will be executed before you even can do a click in the View.

Comment: yes, i got it  know. thank you. Can you please upvote my question?

Comment: since yesterday i was trying ti undesrtand the fragment, and your last comment was of very helpful to me, now i am able more to figure out how fragments work